# Data Type "Time" in mySQL turns into "Datetime" in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, mariadb

I have database with a MariaDB backend and a MS-Access frontend. I have a table with a column with the data type set to "time(6)". In my backend, the column only shows time-values between 00:00 and 23:59. There are no dates in that column.
However, when I open the (linked) table in my Access frontend, it shows date AND time in that column. It always shows the current date and the time value from the backend-table. So if the actual value in the field is "16:25", Access will show "07.02.2023 16:25" (current date in German date format).

I have a form in Access where one can edit the data for a specific recordset. In that form there is also a textbox for the time value. When the textbox is not selected, it will show the correct time (e.g. 16:25). However, as soon as I click into the textbox to edit the time, it will suddenly show date and time (e.g. 07.02.2023 16:25). The format of that textbox is set to "Time, 24h" though.

How can I make the textbox show only the time without date, even when the textbox is selected? Why does my Access frontend interpret the time value as a datetime value?

If I set the property "Show Date picker" of that textbox to "For dates", it will show the date picker after selecting the textbox, despite the fact that the format is set to "Time, 24h". This doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas? Thank you!

I updated the ODBC connection to the table several times, but in my frontend there are still datetime values in the column that should only have time values.

Comment: Probably because there is no datatype TIME in MS-ACCESS (see: [Data types for Access desktop databases](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-types-for-access-desktop-databases-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482) ) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does my Access frontend interpret the time value as a datetime
> value?

That's by design as Access doesn't have discrete data types for date and time.

You can easily read the time only:

```
=TimeValue([YourTimeField])
```

An edit can be done in an unbound textbox. Use the AfterUpdate event of this to write the edited time.

Also, see my article:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html?preview=uzaB%2Bz7eejg%3D).